# Javascript. Variable is not assigned normally

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working on a game that involve color.

```
colors[0] = "RGB(205, 248, 46)";
squares[0].style.background = "rgb(205, 248, 46)";
```

when I do :

```
squares[0].style.background = colors[0];
```

and then to check color of square - it's not assigned, it remains the same as before!:

```
console.log(squares[0].style.background);
"rgb(205, 248, 46)"
```

I need those letters to be Capital.

Comment: Why do you need them to be capital?  That's the browser formatting it (presumably) correctly according to the standards.

Comment: This is the behavior of DOM elements; it cannot be changed.  If you need to, you can do `squares[0].style.background.toUpperCase()` to get the capital RGB.

Comment: `var colors = ["RGB(205, 248, 46)"];` and it works fine... if squares is an array of elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you can't. [The spec actually states](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgb-color) the `rgb` should be lowercase. So the browser is doing you a favor by lowercasing it for you before stashing it away. What you get back later is the correctly formatted string.

If you really need it to be uppercase you can use [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase).

```js
var colors = [];
var squares = document.querySelectorAll('div');
colors[0] = "RGB(205, 248, 46)";
squares[0].style.background = "rgb(205, 248, 46)";

document.querySelector('pre').innerText = squares[0].style.background.toUpperCase();
```

```css
div {
  background: #BEF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in another call to set a secondary attribute as a "literal value".

```
colors[0] = "RGB(205, 248, 46)";
squares[0].style.background = colors[0];
squares[0].setAttribute('data-background-literal', colors[0]);
```

Then access it with this

```
console.log(squares[0].getAttribute('data-background-literal'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the [CSS spec requires that RGB colors use the lowercase prefix](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions), the browser will convert your input (with capital letters) to the proper lowercase value and set the color correctly. However, when fetching it back, you will see the converted (lowercase) value that was actually used, [as seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/28ukeq9c/1/):

```
const squares = [1, 2].map((i) => document.getElementById(`color-${i}`));
const output = document.getElementById('output');

squares[0].style.background = "rgb(205, 248, 46)";
squares[1].style.background = "RGB(205, 248, 46)";

for (let s of squares) {
    output.textContent += s.style.background + '\n';
}
```

There is no requirement for browsers to support the capitalized color, so you should probably avoid it entirely. Converting well before you assign the styles would work, but starting with `rgb(r, g, b)` would be a better option, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to uppercase the letter in CSS by :
    text-transform: uppercase;